# Hash Table - Sort in order of how they are input

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a hash table here and I have it eventually outputting to an Excel spreadsheet, but the issue appears to be the way the system sorts the hash table by default. I want it to return the machines in the same order that they are inputted, they way it currently works is a box pops up and you paste in all your machine names so they are all in memory prior to the `foreach` loop. I was previously sorting this by the longest uptime but it now needs to be the same way they are inputted. My initial thought is to create another hash table and capture them in the same order versus the `$machineList` variable, but that might even leave me in the same position. I tried to search but I couldn't find info on the default way that hash tables sort.

Any ideas?

```
$machineUptime = @{}
foreach($machine in $machineList){
    if(Test-Connection $machine -Count 1 -Quiet){
        try{
            $logonUser = #gets the logged on user
            $systemUptime = #gets the wmi property for uptime

            if($logonUser -eq $null){
                $logonUser = "No Users Logged on"
            }

            $machineUptime[$machine] = "$systemUptime - $logonUser"
        }
        catch{
            Write-Error $_
            $machineUptime[$machine] = "Error retrieving uptime"
        }
    }
    else{
        $machineUptime[$machine] = "Offline"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `$machineUptime` as an ordered hashtable (provided you have PowerShell v3 or newer):

```
$machineUptime = [ordered]@{}
```

Comment: Found this like 5 minutes after, of course. Thanks!

Comment: [ordered] is PowerShell 3.0+