# Powershell refuses to sort hashtable initially or keep it sorted

Tags: function, loops, powershell, hashtable

I have a fairly simple hashtable script in my main block. My variables `hashtable` and `interface` are all global. I am passing a simple value to a function and assigning a value to the global `interface` to be used to create my hashtable.

Here are the functions:

```
Function Get-TestedInterface ($num)
{
    #Determines SAS or SATA by FWCheck.swt prefix convention of 2016.
    switch -Wildcard ($num)
    {
        1* {$interface = "SAS/SATA"}
        2* {$interface = "SAS"}
        3* {$interface = "SAS"}
        4* {$interface = "SATA"}
        5* {$interface = "SAS/SATA"}
        6* {$interface = "SAS"}
        7* {$interface = "SATA"}
        8* {$interface = "SAS/SATA"}
    }
}

#This function test the FwCheck.swt file for any changes
Function Test-Swtpath
{
    #copy file to text format
    cp C:\path\to\FwCheck.swt C:\path\to\fwcheck_working.txt
    sleep -s 1
    #Build a number array
    $sections = @((Select-String -Path C:\path\to\fwcheck_working.txt -Pattern ":(\d{4})").Line)

    #Cycle through sections and check for missing batch files.
    foreach($section in $sections)
    {
        $num = $section -replace ":"
        $t = Test-Path "C:\path\to\FwCheck${num}.bat"
        if($num -ne "5/[1-9]\d{3}/")
        {
            Get-TestedInterface ($num)
        }

        build hash table to allow correct batch file execution
        $hashtable.Add("$num" , "$interface") | Out-Null

        #Build missing batch file.
        if($t -eq $false -and $num -ne "5\d{3}")
        {
            $l = @"
cd\
cd\path\to
program -l${num}-${num} `$c:\path\to\FwCheck.swt
"@
            New-Item "C:\path\to\FwCheck${num}.bat" -ItemType file -Value $l

        }
    }
}
```

I get outputs that are completely in order if I don't use Out-Null so that it shows me my hashtable as I am building it. That means that the hashtable is being built in the correct order.

However, at the end of the function, if I call the `hashtable` variable, it shows all of my entries completely jumbled into an unorganized mess while still being referenced to the correct `interface`.

I have tried to sort using `$states.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name` and putting it in another variable, but I can never get that to work either.

Anything that I'm blatantly missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash Table - Sort in order of how they are input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629439/hash-table-sort-in-order-of-how-they-are-input) and [Hash tables in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264752/hash-tables-in-powershell)

Comment: You're missing the fact that a hashtable, due to its nature, does not preserve insertion order in the first place :-) if you're using PowerShell version 3.0 or newer, you can instantiate it as an ordered dictionary instead with `$hashtable = [ordered]@{}`